# Image in a PHP File

Tags: php, html

I  have a text link in a php file, but I want to make it an image link. The current code is.

```
$link="<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=".rawurlencode($url)."'>".t("Add")."</a>";
```

Now instead word "Add" I want to have an image in there. My current syntax to do that isn't working though, my error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING. Thanks.

Comment: What's your current syntax? And what does the function t() do?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$link="<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=".rawurlencode($url)."'><img src='". $url_to_image ."' alt='' /></a>";
```

I am not sure what variable you have assigned to `$url_to_image` since `t()` looks like a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wrote double quotes inside your string without escaping them, like this:

```
t("<img src="http://asdf.com/jkl.png" />")
```

This would cause the T_STRING error that you mentioned. The correct way of writing this is:

```
t("<img src=\"http://asdf.com/jkl.png\" />")
```

Or you could use single quotes either for delimiting the string or the HTML tag attributes:

```
t("<img src='http://asdf.com/jkl.png' />")
t('<img src="http://asdf.com/jkl.png" />')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all...the error must have been in your function "t". I am assuming that you have a function "t" :)

Here is the simplest way to put the link in instead of the word:

```
$link = "<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=" . rawurlencode($url) . "'><img src='http://www.myimage.com' /></a>";
```

Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code just generating HTML, which you want to look like..

```
<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=abcdef'><img src='image.jpg'></a>
```

To PHP'ify that, you'd do..

```
$link = "<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=".rawurlencode($url)."'><img src='".$url."'></a>";
```

..or, more tidily using sprintf:

```
$link = sprintf("<a target='_blank' href='/stuff/morestuff/?url=%s'><img src='$s'></a>",
    rawurlencode($url),
    $url
);
```